# ; em Javascript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Faz um tempo já que percebi que o JavaScript não liga para ausência de ; entre instruções, desde que haja uma quebra de linha entre elas.
Minha pergunta é: há alguma diferença entre usar ou não usar ; ?

Coloquei um exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw1vtaj4/1/) pra ilustrar melhor o que eu quis dizer

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria, obrigado